# What makes Outlook/Exchange able to resolve a recipient or not?

Tags: python-3.x, email, outlook, exchange-server

I am trying to test whether staff are still employed in the organization.

The best approach I have found so far has to try send them an email.

So, using Outlook, Exchange and Python, I put the email addresses into a new email and try "Resolve" the recipient.

The behavior seems erratic. In most cases, this will produce a result, or "None".

```
for recipient in msg.Recipients:
    try:
        exchangeSays = recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser()
```

But now in my test case, I have a person john.smith@company.com and whilst the person does exist, is real and present, the entry will not resolve.

I've also noticed that sometimes email addresses resolve to "John Smith" and other recipients will resolve to "john.smith@company.com". I know it's resolved when the name is underlined in the email window.

What's going on here? Some questions:

1. Is this the best way of checking whether an person is still current?
2. Am i doing something wrong in my attempt to resolve the recipient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there is no need to create a message and send it - use `Application.Session.CreateRecipient` / `Recipient.Resolve`. If `Recipient.Resolve` returns true, check `Recipient.AddressEntry.Type`, If it is `"EX"`, the name was resolved to a GAL user. You can however run into problems if you have a contact with the same name in your Contacts folder, and OOM does not allow to resolve against a particular container (e.g. GAL).

Note that Outlook Object Model cannot handle ambiguous names (e.g. "John Smith" will also match "John Smither") - it will simply return an error. If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) is an option (I am its author), it exposes `RDOSession.`[AddressBook](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdoaddressbook.htm)`.ResolveNameEx`, which returns a list of matches.

On the Extended MAPI level `(PR_ANR` restriction) you can also resolve against a particular container, but OOM does not expose that functionality. In Redemption, you can use `RDOSession.AddressBook.GAL.ResolveName`/`ResolveNameEx`. Note however that in this case GAL provider won't resolve an SMTP address of a GAL user (go figure).

Outlook (UI only) also exposes search containers (`PR_SEARCH` in MAPI, you can see the one exposed by GAL if you click Ctrl + Shift + B to open the address book, then click Tools | Find). You can specify one or more fields to match (e.g. the whole display name or first and last names separately), but OOM, again, does not expose it. In Redemption, you can use `RDOSession.Addressbook.GAL.Search`:

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set AddrList = Session.Addressbook.GAL
set Search = AddrList.Search
Search.FirstName = "John"
Search.LastName = "Smith"
set AddressEntries = Search.GetResults
for each AddressEntry in AddressEntries
    MsgBox AddressEntry.Name
next
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, that's brilliant - a whole lot more information than I needed or knew about. So using `Application.Session.CreateRecipient / Recipient.Resolve` is very fast and efficient. But testing whether it's type 'EX' (which I understand specifies an Exchange Server address) is a moot point. If the name cannot be resolved, the rest is meaningless.  Thanks again - much appreciated

Comment: True, but if you pass an SMTP address (even if it is invalid in a sense that an email will bounce back) you will get back a one-off resolved recipient since Outlook checks that a name looks like an SMTP address without any extra validation. Ditto for matches against your Contacts folder - you can have stale data there, while GAL is always up-to-date.